# c# foreach loop with class property cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, foreach

I have foreach loop that goes through an array of a class and has an `if` statement that uses one of the class' properties, however it doesn't work. I get this error:

> Board.Boat.length cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

How do you solve that here's the code. Keep in mind it still isn't finished.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;

namespace BattleShip
{
    class Board
    {
        class Boat
        {
            // This class is made for storing the meta-data of each individual boat

            // Determines the start point 
            static int[,] pos = new int[xBoardSize, yBoardSize];
            // Determines the direction of the boat (0 = horizontal, 1 = vertical)
            static int direction = 0;
            // Keeps track of the boat's size
            static int length = 1;
            // Keeps track if tile is hit or untouched
            static int[] stateList;

            // Searches fora oat object and
            static Boat SearchForBoat (Vector2 coords, Boat[] database)
            {
                foreach (Boat boat in database)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < boat.length; i++)
                }
            }

        }

        // These variables determine the size of the board
        static int xBoardSize = 10;
        static int yBoardSize = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you convert all your `static` *members and methods* to the *instance*, you will fix your problem, only use `static` when you absolutely need to. `Boat` should be self-contained... Think about it. If you make 2 boats, should they share the same length? if you move one boats position, should that move all other boats positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `length` property is `static`. Such properties are rather class properites, while others are instance properties, i.e. `static` field are use with type (and the other with instantiated object of a class). In your case it should be `Boat.length` instead of `boat.length`.

Remark: you should consider those static properties, as `length` seems to me like it should depend on particular object, thus should not be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

There error is telling you that you are trying to access a static property from an object instance.

```
foreach (Boat boat in database) // give me each real boat from database
{
    for (int i = 0; i < boat.length; i++) // access an individual boat length
```

However, because length is static, technically the boat instance doesn't have a property called `length`.

I have taken the liberty to SRP ([single responsibility principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and normalize your code

> The single responsibility principle is a computer programming
>   principle that states that every module, class, or function[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) should
>   have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided
>   by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class, module or function.

As such it removed all your [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) guff

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to
>   the type itself rather than to a specific object.

```
public class Board
{
   // These variables determine the size of the board
   public const int XBoardSize = 10;
   public const int YBoardSize = 10;

   // a board has an array of boats, seems logical
   public Boat[] Boats { get; set; }

   // a board can find boats on it
   public Boat SearchForBoat(Vector2 coords )
   {
      foreach (var boat in Boats)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < boat.Length; i++)
            /// do stuff here
      }
   }
}

// concrete boat class, which you can make instances from 
public class Boat
{
   // notice not static, we are saying an individual "boat" can have these properties
   public int[,] Pos = new int[Board.XBoardSize, Board.YBoardSize];
   public int Direction { get; set; }
   public int Length { get; set; } = 1;
   public int[] StateList { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got multiple comments for your code:

1st static is to be considered as something unique. It is something like a global value shared by all object instances

From [Microsoft documentation on static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

> The **static** member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. **Only one copy of a static member exists**, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

With that in mind your `Boat` class will become:

```
public class Boat
{
       // This class is made for storing the meta-data of each individual boat

      // Determines the start point 
      public int[,] pos = new int[xBoardSize, yBoardSize];           
      // Determines the direction of the boat (0 = horizontal, 1 = vertical)
      public int direction = 0;
      // Keeps track of the boat's size
      public int length = 1;
      // Keeps track if tile is hit or untouched
      public int[] stateList;
}
```

Your boats should now be made part of your Board with a `Has-A` relationship:

```
public class Board
    {
         private Boat[] boats;

         public Board(Boat[] boats) {
             // initialize th boats for the specific game
             this.boats = boats
         }

         Boat SearchForBoat (Vector2 coords)
         {
             foreach (Boat boat in boats)
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < boat.length; i++)
             }
         }

          // These variables determine the size of the board
        int xBoardSize = 10;
        int yBoardSize = 10;
}
```

Then you need to initialize via a constructor and use the specific instances

Answer (score 0):

> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < boat.length; i++) //wrong access static from an instance
    for (int i = 0; i < Boat.length; i++) //correct access static from the type itself (class itlsef)
```

read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) for more information